# NAT ports - how do they work?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nat, linux-networking

I have the following network schema:

---

- Computer A: three nics:

  - NIC 1 (eth0): dhcp, public internet
  - NIC 2 (eth1): static 192.168.1.1, gateway for Computer B
  - NIC 3 (eth2): static 192.168.2.1, gateway for Computer C

---

- Computer B: static 192.168.1.2, using gateway 192.168.1.1 (NIC 2).

---

- Computer C: static 192.168.2.2, using gateway 192.168.2.1 (NIC 3).

---

So I applied this to get NAT working:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Every computer can connect to the internet now. I have been applying rules to the main computer (Computer A), like dropping connections to some ports, e.g ssh:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

But for instance, now I would like **only** allow connections for ports 20,21,22,53 and 80 in Computer C, and ignore the outside traffic if it's not related to those ports. The allowed connections should be FROM Computer C to outside, but not from outside to Computer C (I mean - Computer C is not hosting any HTTP or SSH, but it is going to use them as a client).

I guess this sould be done like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The last rule (dropping any other traffic different from those) is at the end of the configuration, so -A should be working correctly.

The thing is... it is not working. If I put the last rule like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j DROP
```

It just drops everything and, for instance, port 21 (previously opened as you can see above) is not either working.

Can you tell me what could I have done wrong? I have been struggling with this problem for some time and I am unable to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You allow outgoing new/established connections for TCP 21 and you allow incoming established connections for TCP 21. But you drop every trafic in forward chain.

I think the issue comes from here then you should add a forward rule to allow outgoing and incoming trafic.